# How to add symbol before String not at first index in android

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have a String from which i have splited from specific symbol and set in into TextView but Problem is that i have to add * before String not in 1st String.

code:-

```
 String planText = preferences.getString("app_text_for_plan_page", "");
    Log.d(TAG, "PlanText***" + planText);
    String[] split = planText.split("\\$");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i=0; i<split.length; ++i){
        if (i>0) builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("*"+split[i]);
        String afterSplitPlanText = builder.toString();
        Log.d(TAG,"FinalString***" + afterSplitPlanText);
        tx_condition.setText(afterSplitPlanText);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add * before String not in 1st String."? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs

Comment: `not in 1st String` then in which?

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you want to concat all strings with a '*' sign into the textview, like "text * text * text".
Then you can easily try that:

```
builder.append((i > 0 ? "*":"")+split[i]);
```

And within your whole code it would look like this:

```
  String planText = preferences.getString("app_text_for_plan_page", "");
    Log.d(TAG, "PlanText***" + planText);
    String[] split = planText.split("\\$");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i=0; i<split.length; ++i){
        if (i>0) builder.append("\n");
        builder.append((i > 0 ? "*":"")+split[i]);
        String afterSplitPlanText = builder.toString();
        Log.d(TAG,"FinalString***" + afterSplitPlanText);
        tx_condition.setText(afterSplitPlanText);
    }
```